# move_uploaded_file returns false but $_FILES error is 0

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to deploy a PHP project built with CodeIgniter framework on a Linux machine.

The moving uploaded file from the temp to the specified directory is not working for some reason.

Info

- PHP 7.2.19
- CentOS 7
- CodeIgniter 3.0.6

Notes

- I have checked the target containing directory exists (no duplicate files existing with same name as the to-be-moved file).
- I have checked the permissions of the directory and it should be fine (I set the group to apache with permissions = owner user)
- Checked the ACL and it's consistent with the ordinary permissions.
- `$_FILES['file']['error'] = 0` (before and after calling `move_uploaded_file`)
- `file_exists` returns true for `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`
- `is_uploaded_file` returns true for `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`
- `open_basedir` is not set
- The uploaded file is less than post and file upload limits.

The last thing to mention, brace yourself, is that there is another copy of the site exist (deployed on the same server with a different directory name) and the upload is working just fine. Diff'ing both directories to catch the different but found nothing (apart from some views with some updates, nothing related to configurations, .htacess whatsoever).

Any clue as what should I look at?

### Update 1

Code:

```
    $createdFileName = NULL;
    $files = $_FILES;
    if (count($files) > 0) {
        $createdFileName = $this->GUID();
        $target_file = './upload/' . $createdFileName;
        $path_info = pathinfo($files["file"]["name"]);
        if (isset($path_info['extension'])) {
                $ext = $path_info['extension'];
        } else /*if (!$ext)*/ {
            $ext = substr($files['file']['type'], strrpos($files['file']['type'], '/') + 1);
        }
        $success = move_uploaded_file($files["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
        if (!$success) {
            $result = json_encode(array('result' => FALSE, 'message' => 'Couldn\'t upload image file'));
        }
    }
```

This is the code that is working with the other project and not working with the project I'm working on.

I learned about the values of `error` and others from remotely debugging the project.

### Update 2

The following is the permissions of the upload directory.

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 demoroot apache 4.0K Jun  9 14:06 upload/
```

The following is the output of `getfacl`:

```
# file: upload/
# owner: demoroot
# group: apache
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

Comment: Slightly more effort than a few other hundred duplicates, but still lacking code + input samples, dir structure, strace or IDE debugging.

Comment: PD of [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/845021) (m_u_f doesn't just *silently* return false)

Comment: @mario, added code snippet and permissions values.

Comment: @mario, The errors flag are set to report if any (error_reporting = -1, display_errors = 1). Nothing is thrown back as error in response. Is there a way to manually check errors if any?

Comment: @mario, the error `move_uploaded_file failed to open stream permission denied` is thrown. Any ideas where that might be from?

Comment: @mario, I just found the answer to my question. Answer posted. I appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: (Please do not ask readers not to suggest potential duplicates. Such suggestions are made in good faith; you may have not found a good duplicate, or you may have not understood how something you thought was not a duplicate is in fact a good solution).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is running the following command

```
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/upload/directory
```

I totally have no idea what this does and why do I have to run it when `getfacl` output seems okay without running the command.